# Layout Attributes and TextView

Tags: android, xml, textview

Some sources tell that `layout_width` and `layout_height` are attributes of the `class LayoutParams`. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

However, we can use these attributes in XML code of TextView class.

```
<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>
```

How can it be possible ?
Does `class TextView` inherits `class ViewGroup` or `class LayoutParams` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question exactly but "wrap_content" and "match_parent" are actually just assigned integers where 
"wrap_content" = -2 and "match_parent" = -1 so that :

```
<TextView
android:id = "@+id/text_view"
android:layout_width="-2"
android:layout_height="-2"
android:text="Hello World!"/>
```

would be the same thing. Does that answer the question?

Comment: When we look at the class TextView, we can see its attributes which are `android:id`, `android:text`. All attributes of TextView are listed in this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html. However, `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` are not placed in this list. They are attributes of class LayoutParams. How can I use `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in XML code of class TextView if they are not TextView's attributes.

Answer (score 0):

View attributes beginning with `layout_` are applied to the view's `LayoutParams`. The available attributes depend on the type of the view's parent (as this defines the particular subclass of `LayoutParams` the view is using).

Answer (score 0):

In Android, every View must declare how much space it takes on the screen.
You can define it in the XML like in the code snippet you showed or define it via LayoutParams in code.

*P.S:*

ViewGroup is actually just a "regular" View (it extends the View class) - a View that specialized in holding children Views.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` are used during the draw method so when the parent (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout..) want to draw his children those params serves as a guide for the parents.